# Peek into Message Queue using Rebus

Tags: c#, message-queue, rebus

I'm trying to run a maintainance task. For this, I want to push a message on application start. When the actual handler runs, it does it's work and defers it to execute again a day later. I don't want to publish this message, if it's already on the queue. Is there a way to peek into the queue? I'm using the SQL transport, so I tried to simply query the DB. However, the table is locked and cannot be read. One other thing to consider is, that there are at least two machines running the same app. This is why I came up with this solutions, since I want to circumvent concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're using the message queue as a scheduler.

If I were you, I would use a simple background timer (e.g. `System.Timers.Timer`) to periodically send a message to yourself, and then you can do your work in the message handler.

If your scheduling requirements are more complex, it might be beneficial to take a look at something like [Quartz .NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

Comment: Yes, that was the intention. The upshot would be, that when the message is only once in the queue, also only one machine would process it. I looked into Quartz.Net, which seems to be a nice framework, but we already have a Task-Runner, where we could schedule, for example, a command line app. I suppose this is also the way I'm going, since everything else seems more like a hack.